# Why isn't there a proper datetime.time type in Pandas or numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataset with people's departure time for work and the time they take to get where they work. Since people generally go to work every weekday, there obviously is no need for a date associated with the data. I leave for work at 8 AM every working day, and return at 5 PM every working day.

Similarly for schools, offices, etc. There are a number of places where date does not matter as much as time. There is also the converse, where time does not matter as much as date. Back to my problem.

My time is coded as an epoch, and converting to datetime is pretty easy:

```
In [1]: df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='m')
        df['time'].head(3)
Out[1]: 0    1970-01-01 06:15:00
        1    1970-01-01 06:17:00
        2    1970-01-01 08:10:00
        Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But there is the pesky `1970-01-01` in there. I want to get rid of it:

```
In [2]: df['time'].dt.time.head(3)
Out[2]: 0    06:15:00
        1    06:17:00
        2    08:10:00
        Name: time, dtype: object
```

Now it is converted into `object`, which is even peskier than having `1970-01-01`, because I cannot do things like:

```
In [3]: df['time'].dt.time + pd.to_timedelta(df['travel'], unit='m')
Out[3]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        TypeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
        < whole bunch of tracebacks. I know what's going on here >
        TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('<m8[ns]')
```

Then there is this [numpy page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html), with tons of examples, but every single one of them has a date component; **none** have only the time component. For example, I quote:

> ```
> >>> np.array(['2007-07-13', '2006-01-13', '2010-08-13'], dtype='datetime64')
> array(['2007-07-13', '2006-01-13', '2010-08-13'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
> ```

The story repeats in this [Pandas page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html). There are numerous examples with only date component, but not a single example with only time component.

Why the lack of love to storing pure time in a manipulatable format? Do I have to resort to converting all of my data into Python's native `datetime.time` type (which will kill me because I have billions of rows to process)? What I am looking for is a way to store only the time component in a manipulatable format. An answer which sheds light in that direction will be accepted.

Comment: You need to define the behavior you want first. Even conversion to Python's native `datetime.time` will not help since `time` plus `timedeltas` raise a TypeError. [The problem with arithmetic on time objects is that it's not
obvious what to do in case of overflow or underflow](http://bugs.python.org/issue1487389#msg54803).

Comment: Yeah right. I forgot about that bit. And honestly, I don't know how to handle it in my case. <sigh> Thanks, @unutbu.

Comment: Actually, it is obvious: I should wrap around. Because when leaving for regular work, a person does not look at the date. So, if departing at 23:45:00 and traveling for 30 minutes to arrive at workplace, the person would arrive at 00:15:00, regardless of date. Thanks, again @unutbu, for reminding me of the conundrum on performing arithmetic on time objects. If you want, then you can post your comment as answer, with the advice to do the arithmetic first, then convert to time objects as required. That is the best answer to this question, and I will accept it.

Comment: @Kartik classic case of programmers assuming they know everything, but introducing bugs just waiting to rear their ugly heads. For example, I work at night. I leave at 9:00PM (21:00) and return home at 6:00AM (6:00). Am I away from home for -15 hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, @unutbu has not posted an answer to this question, but just commented on it, I shall post what worked, and accept it as answer. If later @unutbu does post an answer, I shall accept that.

Basically, as I mention in the question, date component of datetime does not matter to me for this task. Therefore, the simplest solution is to do the arithmetic first, then get just time:

```
(df['time'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['travel'], unit='m')).dt.time
```