# How to convert from 'object/string' to 'time' type in pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to convert the data-type of the **time** column in my dataset.

I found the below command using pandas from here only but while executing I'm getting the date as well in the pre-defined format for all the cells.

```
d2['Time of Card Posting']=pd.to_datetime(d2['Time of Card Posting'],format='%H:%M:%S')
```

PS: I tried the following command as well to extract time from it but it changes the data-type back to object!

```
d2['Time of Card Posting']=pd.to_datetime(d2['Time of Card Posting'],format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
```

Comment: What do you want this to be?  Pandas does not have a native time type. There's datetime, and there's timestamp.

Comment: I want only time as it was previously in the dataset (when the type was object/string)! so, with timestamp can we extract only time (with datetime type)?

Comment: related: [Why isn't there a proper datetime.time type in Pandas or numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34100587/10197418). `pandas` does not handle date and time separately, as @TimRoberts already commented. You either have to use pandas datetime (to get the full datetime / time series functionality) and ignore the date ***or*** use native Python datetime.time (as object in the pandas series) with reduced functionality.

Comment: Why not leave them as strings?  What do you gain as a different type?

Comment: @FObersteiner thank you for commenting & correcting, appreciate it! Could you please elaborate a bit more (maybe with the help of a command) how can I extract 'time' only with datetime as the data-type? Is it same the one I wrote above?

Comment: @TimRoberts if I leave it as string then, I'm not able to get a sorted values for visualization purposes! with datetime type I can perform other operations on it as well

Comment: String times as HH:MM:SS should sort exactly like an integer timestamp of that time.  Right?

Comment: @TimRoberts nope for me, it's not sorting the times if I'm making visualizations using Seaborn library

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, if you just want the time:

```
import pandas as pd

d2 = pd.date_range(
    "2018-01-01", periods=5, freq="H", name="Time of Card Posting"
).to_frame()

d2_new = d2.assign(
    time=lambda x: (
        pd.to_datetime(x["Time of Card Posting"], format="%H:%M:%S").astype(str)
    ).str[-8:]
)
```